# Terminal dashboard in golang using "termui"

Tags: go

I am working on drawing graphs on the terminal itself from inside a go code.I found this (https://github.com/gizak/termui) in golang. And used this(https://github.com/gizak/termui/blob/master/_example/gauge.go) to draw graph in my code.

Problem is this , as we can see in the code( https://github.com/gizak/termui/blob/master/_example/gauge.go ), they are passing g0,g1,g2,g3 all together in the end "termui.Render(g0, g1, g2, g3, g4)".
In my case I don't know how many gauges to draw before hand so I used a list to store gauge objects and then tried to pass list to render.

```
    termui.Render(chartList...)
```

But it creates only one gauge.

This is how I am appending elements in the list.

```
   for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        g0 := termui.NewGauge()
        g0.Percent = i
        g0.Width = 50
        g0.Height = 3
        g0.BorderLabel = "Slim Gauge"
        chartList = append(chartList, g0)
    }
```

what I am getting is a gauge for i=4 only. when I am doing termui.Render(chartList...)
Am I doing something wrong?
PS - I have modified question based on the answer I got in this question.

Comment: Can you print `len(chartList)` immediately before you call `termui.Render` to make sure it's the expected length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good read on [Variadic Functions](https://medium.com/golangspec/variadic-functions-in-go-13c33182b851)

Take a look at the function signature of Render, https://github.com/gizak/termui/blob/master/render.go#L161

```
func Render(bs ...Bufferer) {
```

All you need to do is

```
termui.Render(chatList...)
```

assuming `chartList` is a `[]Bufferer`

**Edit**
You are only seeing one because they are stacking on top of one-another.  To see this add

```
g0.Height = 3
g0.Y = i * g0.Height            // <-- add this line
g0.BorderLabel = "Slim Gauge"
```

From a quick review of the project, it appears there are ways for auto-arranging that have to do with creating rows (and probably columns).  So you might want to explore that, or you will need to manually position your elements.

[image]

Comment: still getting one value only as an output.

Comment: what I am getting is the output for only last element of list. Is there something wrong I am doing while appending elements to list? 

I am adding the code in my question, please have a look.